# Using datepicker in BaseAdapter for a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, baseadapter

My code in BaseAdapter goes as follows

```
    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ((Fragment)UserRequests.this.context).showDialog(999);//Error
        }
    });
```

To show a date picker we need the below code

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(context, myDateListener, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // arg1 = year
        // arg2 = month
        // arg3 = day
        showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
    }
};

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
            .append(month).append("/").append(year));
}
```

I have two problems with this code. Firstly I want to show a datepicker in a fragment called UserRequests. Which I am not able to.I have tried it as below.

```
((Fragment)UserRequests.this.context).showDialog(999);
```

Second one is I am getting a warning that onCreateDialog method is never used. Please explain me. How to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extend UserRequests from [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) and override onCreateDialog in below way.

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //do something
    }
```

More information is in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker)

Comment: A class named FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter and UserRequest is a class that extends Fragment. From BaseAdapter class I need to get the DatePicker in UserRequest Fragment. And one more question can we use Bundle in class extending BaseAdapter.

Comment: You can create another class(say DatePickerFragment) inside UserRequest that will extend DialogFragment. Inside showDialog you can create instance of DatePickerFragment and use it.
Bundle is not passed from BaseAdapter. But you can create and handle it if needed.